# NSTextFinder action on NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nstextview

I'm trying to capture all the `NSTextFinderClient` calls on my custom `NSTextView` subclass.

The show action is called on my `-(void)performTextFinderAction:(id)sender` override, but for find next, find previous, etc. it's not called.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

*Edit:*

If you create a new project and drag an `NSTextView` from interface builder, command-g and command-shift-g (find next and find previous) don't work when the find bar is first responder.

Why is this?

I need a custom subclass of `NSTextView` to respond to the find bar for every event.

Answer (score 3):

I searched in the Apple's TextEdit source code because with TextEdit, the standard search bar within the Text View works fine for command-G (and other shortcuts) even the search field is the first responder.

I found the solution.

Go to your nib for the main menu, and select the "Find" (and related) menu items. They should be bound to the default action called "performFindPanelAction:." Now unbind them and bind to "performTextFinderAction:" of the First Responder instead.

You may not find that action in the First Responder's action list. So you need to add it by yourself in the First Responder's attributes inspector pane.

This was meant by the document below saying

> Before OS X v10.7, the default action for these menu items was performFindPanelAction:. Whenever possible which you should update your implementation to use this new action.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/performTextFinderAction:

Comment: I can add `performFindPanelAction:` to the FirstResponder's action list, but it also asks for the action method's type.  The default value it installs after clicking the `+` button is "id".  Does this need to be changed?  The action method doesn't return a value, so what does this "type" refer to?  Is it the type of the method's single argument?

Comment: I meant to say `performTextFinderAction:`.  In any case, scrolling through the long list of names, I noticed a `FirstResponder` in the middle of all the class names, and used that.  Seems to work as advertised now.

Answer (score 2):

The find bar communicates privately with the client's NSTextFinder instead of calling NSResponder's -performTextFinderAction:. This is necessary to allow find to work when something besides the client has key focus.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have text collapsing.  When someone seeks certain text that is collapsed, I need to show.  Therefore, I need to pick up when those finds are taking place.

Comment: NSTextFinder always sends -scrollRangeToVisible: when it wants to highlight a new match. Could you uncollapse the text in an override of that (then call super)?

Comment: Wouldn't other things hit that a lot too?